# Principal component analysis with random effects?

Tags: r, regression, pca, random-effects-model

How can I do a Principal Component Analyisis considering also the Random Effects? (*)
Is there any R package able to do so?
Something like PCA+lme4  or PCA+nlme.

(*) I mean I want to transform my variables to get a set of values of linearly uncorrelated variables, but taking also into account that I have some random effect variable (repeated measures on each individual).

PD: Maybe it could be done with a bayesian package that does PCA?

Comment: I don't understand what you have in mind. Can you give more concrete example of the data that you would want to apply this hypothetical analysis to? Note that PCA is unsupervised but "mixed effects" is something that refers to regression, i.e. is supervised. That seems like entirely different kettle of fish.

Comment: I was asking just in general.  Anyway I've found a related question, but was about Discriminant Analysis instead of PCA, and didn't got a useful reply: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33372/discriminant-analysis-with-random-effects?rq=1

Comment: "I was asking just in general." — But what problem do you hope to solve this way? If we don't know that, we can't steer you in the right direction.

Comment: I want to fit a linear model (with repeated measures for every person)  with many variables (300), most of the variables won't be significant and they are correlated. I want to avoid collienarity problems, that's why I want to use PCA o some similar method to reduce the problem.  The model tries to explain physiological magnitudes with the age, food and different habits. But I don't think the basic PCA method is designed to work with mixed effects (multilevel).

Comment: You are correct. PCA is basically a mathematical technique (it solves an optimization problem) and does not really yield model estimates, with or without random effects.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to do regression with many possibly correlated variables, how about using ridge regression? I believe the R package `bigRR` can do ridge regression with separate batches of random effects. It's probably better to perform dimension reduction or shrinkage as part of the prediction algorithm, as in ridge regression, than to do it separately and hope your reduced dataset is appropriate for the DV you're trying to predict, as in doing pure PCA followed by regression.